# Sending SMS from a server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sms

Is it possible to send a SMS to a mobile device (iPhone) from a stand alone process running on a remote server.

It sounds like it is not possible because it provides a easy way to spam people once we have their phone number. But just want to confirm by asking here

Comment: It's possible. and what you said it's true, it's easy to spam once you have the phone no, that's why you don't make your phone no to public, beside, SMS gateway charge you every SMS sent.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer, I do developer evangelism part time at Nexmo.*

Certainly possible, here are a few paid SMS APIs:

- [Nexmo](http://nexmo.com)
- [Twilio](http://twilio.com)
- [Tropo](http://tropo.com)

If you *do* try to SPAM people, your account will likely be deactivated. But APIs/Gateways are used everyday by apps that allow people to SMS from an app, to 2nd factor authentication, verify ownership of phone numbers, allow parties to communicate without revealing their numbers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible. In the past I have achieved something similar (2-way communication via SMS) by simply hooking up an old Nokia phone to a Linux machine and sending the text messages via that phone by sending commands through that cable.

There are, of course, services that provide these 'SMS gateways' for a price.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, quite possible. All you need to do is sign up with sms gateway provider and use their API, most have code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it the same why a server would send an eMail... for example if you have a verizon phone number send an eMail to this address:

```
##########@vtext.com
```

(*Where ########## is your cellphone number with no hyphens)

```
AT&T: ##########@txt.att.net 
T-Mobile: ##########@tmomail.net 
Sprint:##########@messaging.sprintpcs.com
```

I hope this helped! Let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many cloud-based SMS gateways for you to use. The [**TextMarks SMS API**](http://www.TextMarks.com/api/) allows you to easily send SMS, receive SMS, and offers tons of higher level functionality like group management, opt-outs, etc. to help you build your app.

Regarding your SPAM question, TextMarks will not allow you to send messages to people until they have "opted in" (such as by texting your keyword to a specific 5 digit number).

I actually wrote a lot of the extensive TextMarks API docs and would be happy to help you integrate your app.